Appengine runtime from java 8 to 11 - Issues in Local & Deployment Run
When I run the code in my local with the command ("clean install package exec:java -Dexec.args="target/appName-1.war") then I am getting below error message>> Fil Not Found: War File =>  (Access is denied) error.

Absolute Pathname \target\appName-1.war2024-09-12
23:33:48.330:INFO::{PackagePath}.ServerMain.main():
Logging initialized @150281ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog
2024-09-12
23:33:48.390:INFO:oejs.Server:{PackagePath}.ServerMain.main():
jetty-9.4.54.v20240208; built: 2024-02-08T19:42:39.027Z; git:
cef3fbd6d736a21e7d541a5db490381d95a2047d; jvm 11.0.19+9-LTS-224
2024-09-12
23:36:34.639:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:{PackagePath}.ServerMain.main():
Failed startup of context
o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@6c2d7b1c{/,null,STOPPED}{\target\appName-1.war}
java.io.FileNotFoundException: \target\appName-1\LICENSE
(Access is denied)    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native
Method)   at
java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:298)    at
java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:237)
at
java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:187)
at
org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource.JarResource.copyTo(JarResource.java:216)
at
org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebInfConfiguration.unpack(WebInfConfiguration.java:658)
at
org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebInfConfiguration.preConfigure(WebInfConfiguration.java:143)
at
org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.preConfigure(WebAppContext.java:488)
at
org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:523)
at
org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
at
org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:423)   at
org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:110)
at
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:387)     at
org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
at
{PackagePath}.ServerMain.main(ServerMain.java:65)
at
org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo.lambda$execute$0(ExecJavaMojo.java:283)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) 2024-09-12
23:36:34.663:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:{PackagePath}.ServerMain.main():
Started ServerConnector@f4e0fa0{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:8080}
2024-09-12
23:36:34.664:INFO:oejs.Server:{PackagePath}.ServerMain.main():
Started @316618ms

Here with I have shared the POM file and Server Main file.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1</version>

    <groupId>com.cmpny</groupId>
    <artifactId>AppName</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <appengine-sdk-version>1.9.54</appengine-sdk-version>
        <gcloud.plugin.version>0.9.58.v20150505</gcloud.plugin.version>
        <objectify.version>5.1.15</objectify.version>
        <guava.version>20.0</guava.version>
        <spring-version>4.3.6.RELEASE</spring-version>

        <spring-security-version>4.2.1.RELEASE</spring-security-version>
        <spring-ldap-version>2.0.1.RELEASE</spring-ldap-version>

        <spring-data-jpa-version>1.11.0.RELEASE</spring-data-jpa-version>
        <hibernate-version>4.3.10.Final</hibernate-version>

        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        <maven.compiler.showDeprecation>true</maven.compiler.showDeprecation>
        <jetty>9.4.54.v20240208</jetty>
        <sonar.qualitygate.wait>true</sonar.qualitygate.wait>
        <webapp.dir>./src/main/webapp</webapp.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>

    </properties>

    <prerequisites>
        <maven>3.6.3</maven>
    </prerequisites>

    <profiles>

        <profile>
            <id>local</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <appengine.application>GCPProjectID</appengine.application>
                <appengine.version>dev</appengine.version>
            </properties>
            <build>
                <filters>
                    <filter>src/main/resources/profiles/local.properties</filter>
                </filters>
            </build>
        </profile>


        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <appengine.application>GCP Project Id</appengine.application>
                <appengine.version>v1-0-0</appengine.version>
            </properties>
            <build>
                <filters>
                    <filter>src/main/resources/profiles/dev.properties</filter>
                </filters>
            </build>
        </profile>

    </profiles>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty}</version>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-util</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>apache-jsp</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
            <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>${appengine-sdk-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-endpoints</artifactId>
            <version>${appengine-sdk-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.jdo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdo-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp</groupId>
            <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.5</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>${guava.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.objectify</groupId>
            <artifactId>objectify</artifactId>
            <version>${objectify.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security-version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-data-jpa-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-search-infinispan</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-openid</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.49</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.sql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-socket-factory</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.3</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.33.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2-b02</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.24</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.directory.server</groupId>
            <artifactId>apacheds-all</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-M20</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20160212</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr250-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.json-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.4</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.oltu.oauth2</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-services-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>v1-rev145-1.25.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.1</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.5</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <artifactId>jetty-servlets</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <version>9.4.31.v20200723</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <targetPath>META-INF</targetPath>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <outputDirectory> ${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>display-dependency-updates</goal>
                            <goal>display-plugin-updates</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.1</version>

            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>{PackagePath}.ServerMain</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-web-resources</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/classes/META-INF/resources</outputDirectory>
                                
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>./src/main/webapp</directory>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>
                                        {packagepath}.ServerMain</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${jetty}</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>

Server Main class:
import java.io.File;

import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.Configuration.ClassList;
import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext;

public class ServerMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("args" + args[0]);
        
        File f = null;
        String path = "";
        boolean bool = false;
        try {

            f = new File("target/<AppName>-1.war");

            bool = f.exists();

            if (bool) {

                path = f.getAbsolutePath();

                System.out.print("Absolute Pathname " + path);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        System.setProperty("org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.class", "org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StrErrLog");
        System.setProperty("org.eclipse.jetty.LEVEL", "INFO");

        int port = Integer.parseInt(System.getenv().getOrDefault("PORT", "8080"));
        Server server = new Server(port);

        WebAppContext webapp = new WebAppContext();
        webapp.setContextPath("/");
        webapp.setWar(path);
        ClassList classlist = ClassList.setServerDefault(server);

        classlist.addBefore("org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.JettyWebXmlConfiguration",
                "org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration");

        server.setHandler(webapp);

        server.start();
        System.out.println("Server started!");
        server.join();
    }
}

Could you help to fix the above issue.

The f.getAbsolutePath() somehow returned a path on windows without a drive letter?  That's a weird JVM bug, and the source of your issue.

The "File Not Found" error is occurring during the unpack of the war to the temporary / work directory.
The specific "FileNotFoundException: \target\appName-1\LICENSE (Access is denied)" you are seeing is referring to is the destination file reference (called LICENSE) when it is opened to be written to.
The same file named LICENSE from the war file is attempting to be copied to the destination location during this unpack and failed.
What we do not know is why, that detail, that information, is missing from your question.
The most obvious thing that stands out is that the resulting absolute path string seems to be missing a drive letter on your windows machine.
Try using path = f.getCanonicalPath(); instead.
Your path String should have a fully qualified and absolute path string to the war.
If you are on windows, that should include the drive letter.  (Using a UNC path or network path is unsupported on Jetty 9, support for those kinds of base resources was added in Jetty 12)
Other things to look for is if that destination location happens to have file permission issues, or a conflicting file or directory entry that is messing up the unpack step.
On windows, it's not hard to have a war file that has two license entries.  one entry as a directory called license\ and one at LICENSE as a file, if the directory gets unpacked first, then the file will never be able to be unpacked.
These kinds of weird scenarios are not adequately reported on the EOL Jetty 9.x series.  Jetty 12 has vastly improved the error/warnings when encountering theses kinds of quirky war files.

f.getAbsolutePath(); & f.getCanonicalPath(); are giving same value and still unable to reach the war file under the target folder and got access denied error. Not sure why I am getting the File not found error even the war file is presented. Any alternative method or approach would help me to fix this issue.

I added more details to my answer
